# Where are the rules for a knight?

Tags: dnd-4e

I know that there is a Knight in D&D 4e, but I want to know where the detailed rules are for this kind of Fighter. I want to check if it has some other powers than the one I have from a template.

Answer (score 7):

The **[Knight](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=713)** is found in *Heroes of the Fallen Lands*, or I linked to the DDI description if you have access to that.

It is a fighter variant.  This means you can replace Knight powers with Fighter powers of the same (or lower) level.

Comment: Also, Eladrins have a variant Knight in dragon magazines (can't remember which one at the moment).

Comment: But only powers that have a level. So, neither Battle Guardian (Fighter Attack) or Defender Aura (Fighter Utility) - which both lack a level - can be swapped for a Fighter (Weaponmaster) at-will or utility power.